# Powershell hangs on Launch

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

When I run powershell ISE, I can execute commands/scripts without issue.  When I launch either the 32 or 64 bit command line, the window takes about 30 seconds to load and then it is frozen.  It will not accept inputs of any kind (keyboard or copy/paste).  I have tried doing a system check, no errors.  I even tried updating to powershell 4.0, the install was successful but the command line still locks on launch.  Can anyone advise how to fix this?  I am using windows server 2008 R2.

**Update**
It appears that the powershell is in fact accepting input, except at a glacial speed.  I left the window open while I was writing this post initially, and then grabbed a coffee.  Upon my return I found that what I have tried to copy/paste and type was now in the powershell command line.  I have now attempted to execute $PSVersionTable.PSVersion, and going on 3 minutes now I still have no response.  My guess is it will come back at some point but this is obviously not acceptable.  Any ideas on how to debug/fix this?

**Update2**
As far as I can tell all the locations listed in $PROFILE | Select * don't exist.  I also tried launching: powershell.exe -noprofile, but this did not help

Comment: Look at `$PROFILE | select *` locations, and disable them to remove that as a possibility.

Comment: *cough* AntiVirus

Comment: @KoryGill I'm not that familiar with powershell configuration and I tried to google 'disable powershell profiles' but most links simply explain what $PROFILE is and how you can add things to it.  Could you explain how to 'disable' these?

Comment: To disable them, rename them to something other than what they are named now.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Thanks for that!  I had similar problems and it ended up being Bitdefender: https://superuser.com/q/1377171/266909

Comment: @NelsonRothermel haha, brilliant :D

Comment: I had a similar issue (not Server, but Win10 Pro desktop); while I'm not 100% sure, it started happening when I enabled long pathnames on the system and apparently went away when I disabled it (obviously in my case there was no high disk/resource activity after opening PS, and it didn't recover from the hang even after ~1h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [this post](https://www.sepago.de/blog/powershell-response-is-slow-after-each-command-on-command-line-get-childitem-start-a-script-dir-etc/) I decided to try that tool and see if I had a similar problem and discovered that there were literally hundreds of writes per second happening when powershell command line was running and they were all to the FusionLog.  Disabling the Fusion logging fixed the issue completely (this was enabled a while ago to debug a different issue with an app and I must have forgotten to disable it).  Everything else on the machine seemed to hum along just fine with FusionLogging in the background but powershell was horribly crippled.  Hope this helps someone some day.

Comment: That's worth a vote for solving the issue -- even if it is your own... Only other suggestion would have been to fire up `taskmgr` to see where the CPU cycles were going.

Comment: the blog post appears to have moved to https://www.sepago.de/blog/powershell-response-is-slow-after-each-command-on-command-line-get-childitem-start-a-script-dir-etc/

Comment: What are steps to disable Fusion logging?

Comment: @DimaLituiev A quick google search gives you:
https://www.dotnetcodegeeks.com/2015/08/dot-net-enable-and-disable-fusion-log-to-investigate-assembly-loading-issues.html

Comment: the post mentions using this tool to identify the issue, and in their case the solution was to delete the text file at `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt`. This worked for me as well. Not sure if it will work for everyone though.